# Arrow Functions in Angular2 Typescript - IE11

Tags: angular, typescript, arrow-functions

Will arrow functions written in Typescript for Angular2 work in IE 11? I've read that arrow functions in javascript aren't supported in IE 11 but wasn't sure if this meant they would also not be supported in Typescript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TypeScript code gets compiled to JavaScript, and you can specify to which JavaScript version you'd like it to compile to. Whether the generated code will work, depends on the compilation target you have specified in `tsconfig.json` file or through command-line options for `tsc`. As long as you have `ES5` as a target, the compiled code will work in IE11.

To read more about Compiler Options, see [official TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Answer (score 1):

Arrow function in ES 6 specifications are supported in the below list of browsers,

[image]

**[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**